# Is there any software that can fix texts to specific page and place?

Tags: ebooks, books, desktop-publishing, reader

**In MS-Word (and its free alternatives)**, if I insert a few lines or paragraphs of texts, the all remaining texts dramatically changes their places and page number. I need to specify page numbers, contents, indexes which will not be affected due to minor edits.

My question is, What software do you recommend a document editing software that can hold the texts in specific page numbers?

**What I have tried:**

1. Using **MS Powerpoint** (and its free alternatives) with page size A4 and portrait layout.

Problem: Initially it seemed to be an excellent solution. But Tables and charts are difficult to format. Text readability not as good as MS Word. Every time a text box is required. Lot other basic MS-Word feature missing.

2. Tried **insertion of page break**, **insertion of blank page**, **turning on/ off the "widow/orphan control**", etc.

Problem: The page numbers keep changing.

3. Googled about any such MS office feature

Result- not found anything helpful. Even a Microsoft tech support said they yet have not developed this feature to keep text in definite page number.

**Additional question 1**

Is there any way to automatically create content-page and/or index page just like there are some  MS word option for inserting document cover, headings and subheadings, endnotes and cross-reference, etc.

**Additional question 2**

What software is used by book publishers for writing/formatting of books? (for similar features)?

Comment: Where do you expect the text at the end of the page will go if you insert some lines in the middle of the page? What you want is not how word processors work.

Comment: @DavidPostill if this functionality requirement goes beyond definition of an word processor, then recommend me software from some other category that also can give these functionalities.